# Displaying results with Exp instead of powers

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Entering

```
Solve[z^4 == -1]
```

gives:

> {{z -> -(-1)^(1/4)}, {z -> (-1)^(    1/4)}, {z -> -(-1)^(3/4)}, {z ->
> (-1)^(3/4)}}

or $\left\{\left\{z\to -\sqrt[4]{-1}\right\},\left\{z\to \sqrt[4]{-1}\right\},\left\{z\to -(-1)^{3/4}\right\},\left\{z\to (-1)^{3/4}\right\}\right\}$

It is possible to have the output as:

```
{{z -> Exp[I*Pi/4]}, {z -> Exp[I*3 Pi/4]}, {z ->     Exp[I*5 Pi/4]}},
{z -> Exp[I*7 Pi/4]}
```

$$\left\{\left\{z\to \exp \left(\frac{i \pi }{4}\right)\right\},\left\{z\to \exp \left(\frac{i 3 \pi }{4}\right)\right\},\left\{z\to \exp \left(\frac{i 5 \pi }{4}\right)\right\}\right\},\left\{z\to \exp \left(\frac{i 7 \pi }{4}\right)\right\}$$

(with $i$ instead of $I$)

How can these points be plotted for  visualization?

Thanks.

Comment: Overall, many thanks to everyone who has contributed. All the responses make me realise how little I know about Mathematica and leaves me wondering how I can gain a fraction of the knowledge shown in the given answers.

Comment: Thanks also @Syed for tidying up my question 

Comment: You can upvote any of the answers on the page by clicking the triangles (UP). As the OP, you can also accept one answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This is the standard way of saying "Thanks" on all stack sites. We hope to see you again soon.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Thanks @Syed for the links. Is there a Mathematica book specifically covering Maths including calculus and complex analysis?

Comment: [Shaw 2014](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/complex-analysis-with-mathematica/EDF46A1269544C6A6B7D2FFF1BC7CC2F), [Filipuk/Kozlowski's](https://www.degruyter.com/serial/fam-b/html?lang=en) series as well as [Mathematica by Example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780128124819/mathematica-by-example) are a few examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pts = Solve[z^4 == -1, z]
```

> {{z -> -(-1)^(1/4)}, {z -> (-1)^(    1/4)}, {z -> -(-1)^(3/4)}, {z ->
> (-1)^(3/4)}}

```
Abs[z] E^(I Arg[z]) /. pts
```

Or

```
Flatten@({First@# Exp [ I (Last@#)]} & /@ (AbsArg[z] /. pts))
```

$$\left\{e^{-\frac{1}{4} (3 i \pi )},e^{\frac{i \pi }{4}},e^{-\frac{1}{4} (i \pi )},e^{\frac{3 i \pi }{4}}\right\}$$

As I read Bob Hanlon's answer, I realized that I chose the default argument answer. For an argument between 0 and 2π, you can try this variation:

```
MapThread[Times, {Abs[z] /. pts, Exp@Mod[Arg[z] /. pts, 2 π] }]
```

You can also try `// TraditionalForm` if it is for display purposes only.

To plot:

```
ComplexListPlot[z /. pts, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Circle[]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Nasser Thank you Syed and Nasser for your quick replies. Both produce the required output, with Syed's also producing the graph. How would I add a surrounding circle at, say, 2, centred at 0?

Comment: @Davo `ComplexListPlot[z /. pts, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, 2]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much 

Answer (score 6):

```
sol = SolveValues[z^4 == -1, z]
ResourceFunction["ComplexToPolar"] /@ sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sol = Solve[z^4 == -1]

(* {{z -> -(-1)^(1/4)}, {z -> (-1)^(1/4)}, {z -> -(-1)^(3/4)}, {z -> (-1)^(3/4)}} *)
```

To convert to polar

```
sol2 = sol /. z_?NumericQ :> Abs[z]*Exp[I*Arg[z]]

(* {{z -> E^(-((3 I π)/4))}, {z -> E^((I π)/4)}, {z -> 
   E^(-((I π)/4))}, {z -> E^((3 I π)/4)}} *)

Values[sol] == Values[sol2]

(* True *)
```

Note that Mathematica automatically converts the arguments to the interval {-Pi, Pi}

```
{{z -> Exp[I*Pi/4]}, {z -> Exp[I*3 Pi/4]}, {z -> Exp[I*5 Pi/4]}, {z -> 
   Exp[I*7 Pi/4]}}

(* {{z -> E^((I π)/4)}, {z -> E^((3 I π)/4)}, 
    {z -> E^(-((3 I π)/4))}, {z -> E^(-((I π)/4))}} *)
```

To get the form that you requested would require something along the lines of

```
sol3 = sol /. 
  z_?NumericQ :> Abs[z]*Exp[Inactive[Times][I, Mod[Arg[z] + 2 Pi, 2 Pi]]]
```

[image]

```
sol2 === Activate[sol3]

(* True *)
```

Comment: I like that the output avoids negative Pi. Very clever! Many thanks Bob.

Answer (score 5):

Using Syed's idea and Bob Hanlon's idea with `ComplexExpand`:

```
SetAttributes[ToComplexExp, Listable]
ToComplexExp[expr_?NumericQ] := 
Abs[expr]*Exp[HoldForm[I]*Mod[Arg[ComplexExpand[expr]], 2 Pi]]
```

Your example:

```
sol = SolveValues[z^4 == -1, z]

(*{-(-1)^(1/4), (-1)^(1/4), -(-1)^(3/4), (-1)^(3/4)}*)
```

Test:

```
Sort@ToComplexExp[sol]
```

[image]

Using `ToComplexExp` with `Solve`:

```
sol = Flatten@Solve[z^4 == -1, z]
```

Test:

```
Sort[MapAt[ToComplexExp, #, {2}] & /@ sol]
```

[image]